# Contact form does not send to the designated email

Tags: php, forms, contacts

Please help with below contact form. It doesn't seem to send the to designated email.

The codes for the form:

```
<h4 class="bolder">Leave a Message</h4>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <p>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" class="span3" type="text">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="span3" type="email">
        <label for="comment">Message</label>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="span5" cols="15" rows="3"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

The codes for the submit action:

```
$message="$comment";
$mail_from="$email";
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
$to ='partnersys.solutions@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$message,$header);

if($send_contact)
{
    echo "We've recived your contact information";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: It might be that your webserver doesn't allow mail().

Comment: Your call to `mail()` is missing a subject parameter, which won't help. There could be a dozen other reasons why the mail isn't being delivered.

Comment: You have two open form tags... and only one closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a more optimized code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $email_to = "partnersys.solutions@gmail.com"; 

    function died( $error )
    {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['full_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['comments']))
    {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from))
    {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$full_name))
    {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2)
    {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0)
    {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_subject .= clean_string($subject);
    $email_message .= "Full name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

    echo 'We\'ve recived your contact information';
}
?>


<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Contact us </title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
        <input  type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="First and last name(optional)" maxlength="50" size="30">
        <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="80" size="30">
        <input  type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="30" size="30">
        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Message goes here." cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="widthfix">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place it all into one file.

Comment: it doesnt work. the first part is not executing instead shows code in the page. the 2nd part works. how to send an attachment? please help

Comment: Of course it isn't, you have to wrap the first part of the php code in it's parameters. There it's been edited. Use it now.

Comment: hi thanks but it seems to be a problem here

Comment: at if(strlen($error_message) > 0) onward? i have added the parameter as requested but the codes after the above seems to have some problems? i not sure. please help.

Comment: please see the http://sungrain.my/contact.html please help where i am going wrong

Comment: You need to save that as contact.php instead of contact.html

Comment: hi thanks alot its working now. i am trying the form to vertical instead of horizontal. i mean the fields to be below to each other. also how can i increase the size of the text area. please help.

Comment: Accept the answer as it has helped you. I suggest you create a new question for that, then I can help you. Leave the link here once done.

Comment: one more question regarding this, how can i add a few emails that form to be sent. thanks

Comment: You still have not accepted the answer. Also, I believe that you could just do foreach and then enter emails by commas but you must strip then.

Comment: not sure how to accept the answer. honestly not sure what you mean by I believe that you could just do foreach and then enter emails by commas but you must strip then

Comment: Beside my answer there is a checkmark. As I said, create a new question concerning your problem and leave a link here.